# Thread not stopping until Thread.join() on Windows

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, sockets

The method `stopServer()` the server works perfectly on Mac, Linux, and UNIX computers, but when I try to close on Windows, I find that it takes a minimum of one second **each** for the sockets to close due to the timeout of the `ServerSocket`. I want them to close all at once as they do in Linux, Mac, etc. as opposed to one at a time when I call `Thread.join()`.

**Server Code**

```
public class FileServer {

    private ArrayList<Thread> sockets = new ArrayList<>();
    private ServerSocket fileServer;

    public void startServer(int port, int maxThreads, int timeout) throws IOException {

        fileServer = new ServerSocket();
        fileServer.setPerformancePreferences(1, 0, 1);
        fileServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

        for (int threads = 0; threads < maxThreads; threads++) {
            sockets.add(new Thread(new ServerInit(fileServer, timeout)));
            System.out.println("Socket " + threads + " initialized...");
        }

        for (int socket = 0; socket < sockets.size(); socket++) {
            (sockets.get(socket)).start();
            System.out.println("Socket " + socket + " started!");
        }
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        if (fileServer.isBound()) {
            for (int thread = 0; thread < sockets.size(); thread++) {
                sockets.get(thread).interrupt();
            }
            for (int thread = 0; thread < sockets.size(); thread++) {
                try {
                    if (sockets.get(thread).isAlive()) {
                        sockets.get(thread).join();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServerInit implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket server;
    private int timeout;

    public ServerInit(ServerSocket server, int timeout) {
        this.server = server;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                server.setSoTimeout(1000);
                Socket client = server.accept();
                client.setSoTimeout(timeout);
                processRequest(receiveRequest(client), client);
                client.close();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Socket closed");
    }
}
```

Why is it that the threads are **requiring** me to join them before they will exit the `while` loop? I have tested and am sure that every thread is starting and that every thread is being interrupted properly.

Also, only one thread will print properly if I put `System.out.println()` in the `while` loop.

**EDIT**

I am way more than aware that it has to wait for `accept` to timeout. That is intended, thus only a one second timeout. This all **works** perfectly on other platforms. I am interrupting all threads then joining them in order to make sure that they actually stop. My biggest concern is why these threads aren't timing-out concurrently as they should be.

Comment: How exactly are you imagining this works? The thread is in `accept`, it gets interrupted. Do you think an InterruptedException is thrown? By convention, that clears the interrupt flag, which is all that you are checking.

Comment: There is nothing in the Javadoc that states that `ServerSocket.accept()` is interruptible, so your threads are all waiting for the accept timeout. Your code is working as designed. Interesting that it's faster on some platforms, but there's nothing wrong with the way it's operating on Windows. Your title is meaningless.

Comment: Why not use a volatile static variable (semaphore) in while loop of the `ServerInit` class to stop the threads instead of checking the interrupt flag?

Comment: @EJP: seems to me that should only cause a one second delay in total, not one second per thread.  Unless the call to `.interrupt()` in the main thread has to wait for the `accept()` to time out in each child thread?

Comment: I think you need more debugging statements to make sure you understand the exact sequence of events, i.e., print the time before and after each call to `.interrupt()` as well as before and after each call to `.join()` and when checking `.interrupted()` in each thread.  Edit your question to show the changes and to include the output (for a simple case, e.g., five threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *nix operating systems, the socket implementation doesn't lock on `accept` anywhere along the way.

For Windows, the `PlainSocketImpl` class [defines `accept` as `synchronized`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a71d26266469/src/windows/classes/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java#l193):

```
protected synchronized void accept(SocketImpl s) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

What happens is that `accept` is only being executed by one thread at a time.  The 1 second timeout is only taken in to account by the native `accept`, after the lock is finally acquired.

I can't tell if this is intentional, you must ask in the Java mailing lists.